# How to modify the screen resolution on Kivy-iOS

Tags: python, ios, kivy

I'm working on an app using the python/Kivy-iOS toolchain. For some reason, when I build to the iPhone5, the app doesn't run fullscreen (there's letterboxing at the top and bottom, see attached screenshot). This seems to be the default behavior for Kivy on iOS.

Any idea how to set the resolution manually or make it detect resolution properly?

[image: iPhone Screenshot with Letterboxing]

Comment: Hi, please report the issue on the project and touch a word on the kivy-dev mailing list. As a dev on the project, i don't own an iphone5, so it's hard to test and fix the issue, but we can work together to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: @tito Please let us know if this issue gets resolved!

Comment: @tito I'd love to help resolve this issue. Thanks for the response. https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/1097

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iPhone5 requires a launch image with following properties for it to enable full 4" screen size for your app

- file name - "Default-568h@2x.png"
- dimensions - 640x1136

Place in your app-kivyapp/ directory or add them via xcode's settings interface and you are good to go.